# Extending array to source file from header file in C

Tags: c, arrays, header-files

Is there a way to extend one really big array from header file to source file, and use his elements in main program?

array like this

```
BYTE codes[95][8] = {            
255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 255, 134, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 143, 255, 143, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
235, 128, 235, 143, 235, 255, 255, 255, 
237, 213, 128, 213, 219, 255, 255, 255, 
157, 155, 247, 226, 220, 255, 255, 255, 
201, 112, 170, 221, 250, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 175, 129, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 227, 221, 190, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 190, 221, 227, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
235, 247, 193, 247, 235, 255, 255, 255, 
247, 247, 193, 247, 247, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 250, 249, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
247, 247, 247, 247, 247, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 252, 252, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
253, 251, 247, 239, 223, 255, 255, 255, 
193, 186, 182, 174, 193, 255, 255, 255, 
255, 222, 128, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
222, 188, 186, 182, 206, 255, 255, 255, 
189, 190, 174, 150, 185, 255, 255, 255, 
};
```

Comment: just include this header file in your source file like #include "array_hearder.h"

Answer (score 2):

Never define any variables in header files. It creates linker problems and is bad program design. Instead, this array should be declared as

```
const BYTE codes[95][8] = { ...
```

and placed in a .c file. You can then have a corresponding .h file with

```
extern const BYTE codes[95][8];
```

Include the .h file from the caller and you will get access to the array.

Answer (score 0):

What is

> *"extend .... from header file to source file"*?

If I understood correctly, you want to access the `codes` array from the source file. For that you need to `#include` the header file to the source file and make use of the array `codes`. Remember, it will be in *global* scope (if that matters).

Having said that, as metioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31071183/2173917) by Mr. [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) the best approach is to

- **Declare** the variable(s) [which needs to be used across several translation units (source files)] in the header file.
- **Define** the variable(s) in one of the sopurce files.
- `#include` the header file in *all* the source files and make use of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to put data like this in a header file.

Include guards will not prevent the array from being re-defined in multiple compilation units. This will wreak havoc with the link stage.

Put it in a source file instead and use `extern` if multiple compilation units require `codes`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to define part of the array initializer list in one file and have the remainder of the initializer list in another file.

This is a case where, yes, you can do that - but IMO you probably don't want to.  I think it's brittle, prone to failure, awkward to maintain, and for myself I can't picture *why* this would be needed. However, if you insist, here's an implementation of how it can be done:

array_test.h

```
unsigned char codes[95][8] = {            
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 255, 134, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 143, 255, 143, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  235, 128, 235, 143, 235, 255, 255, 255, 
  237, 213, 128, 213, 219, 255, 255, 255, 
  157, 155, 247, 226, 220, 255, 255, 255, 
  201, 112, 170, 221, 250, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 175, 129, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 227, 221, 190, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 190, 221, 227, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  235, 247, 193, 247, 235, 255, 255, 255, 
  247, 247, 193, 247, 247, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 250, 249, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  247, 247, 247, 247, 247, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 252, 252, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  253, 251, 247, 239, 223, 255, 255, 255, 
  193, 186, 182, 174, 193, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 222, 128, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  222, 188, 186, 182, 206, 255, 255, 255, 
  189, 190, 174, 150, 185, 255, 255, 255,
```

array_test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "array_test.h"

  247, 247, 193, 247, 247, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 250, 249, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  247, 247, 247, 247, 247, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 252, 252, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  253, 251, 247, 239, 223, 255, 255, 255, 
  193, 186, 182, 174, 193, 255, 255, 255, 
  255, 222, 128, 254, 255, 255, 255, 255, 
  222, 188, 186, 182, 206, 255, 255, 255, 
  189, 190, 174, 150, 185, 255, 255, 255 
  };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  printf("whatever\n");
  }
```

Note that the initializer list for `codes` is not terminated in `array_test.h` (in other words, there's no `};` at the end of the initalizer list for `codes`), so the continuation of the list must immediately follow the include of `"array_test.h"`. It also makes the program look odd - when looking at `array_test.c` the continuation of the initializer list appears to be syntactically incorrect, and yet it compiles (using `cc array_test.c` on HP-UX). I don't recommend doing this - but it's an interesting case I had not thought of before.

Best of luck.

Comment: weird...but innovative idea. Just pray no one should get inspired by this coding style . :P